# Formatting Currency from within a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, format, currency, itemtemplate

I have a ListView with an ItemTemplate. The data is bound correctly, but I cannot get the Estimate to format as Currency. I tried 3 different ways, including an IValueConverter, but it doesn't seem to work.

I can format Estimate as Currency outside of the ItemTemplate so I am guessing it is something about ItemTemplate or TextBlock that I don't know...

[image]

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1" >
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 20 0"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding CustomBackgroundColor}"/>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobID}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CustomerName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding JobName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Estimate, Converter={StaticResource formatter}, ConverterParameter='\{0:C\}'}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Estimate, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture={x:Static sysglb:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Estimate, StringFormat='{}{0:c}', Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: That third line works fine for me, must be something else overriding it.

Comment: @mjordan: What type is `Estimate`? If it is a `string` there is no string format applied.

Comment: That's the problem. Where the Estimate formatting works on my Page I have converted it to a property of type decimal. On the other hand, ListView is bound directly to the DataView where Estimate has DataColumn of type string. Thank you both for pointing me in the right direction!